# Angular form select option value equals option text

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, select

I'm using this example of nested cascading selects http://jsfiddle.net/jhsousa/Mekhy/ ... I've got it in a form which when submits emails the values of the select options through. I've added NAME="" and ID="" to achieve this. However only a number is sent through.

How can I get the selected option .value to equal the .text which it is populated by?

This is my first experience with Angular so not having any joy.

I tried adding:
    `obj.value as obj.text for obj in array`
to the ng-options. But the entire thing stopped working because ng-options already has a value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no NICE way to get the text.

The only way is to activate a function call that loop through the Dropdown options elements and find the correct ID and extract the text from the optons.

Comment: I thought it might need to be done using the event for selecting an option.    'ng-change="changeContinent()"'